# Establish a Read-Only ADODB connection to a database through VBA / Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I've been using this code for a long time, but recently a customer asked me if it was possible to establish the connection as a read-only connection, to make extra sure no data was overwritten when using my excel-tool.

There are many previous posts that solve this when data is read from a file, but I cannot find any answers that does this when connecting to a database (well, at least none that worked at least).

I usually put the code in a class module and dim it in my code where I need to submit SQL's. The great thing about having it in a class module is that I never seem to have any problems with the connection being open after execution is halted.

Anyone knows anything to add to this code to make sure that the connection cannot be used to submit update SQLs?

And yes, ideally this would be set on the SQL-server instead of on my end, but... :)

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Connection As ADODB.Connection

Public Sub init()

    Dim Server As String
    Dim Database As String

    Server = Worksheets("K").Cells(3, 3) '  <== This cell contains the name of the Database Server
    Database = Worksheets("K").Cells(3, 4) '  <== This cell contains the name of the Database

    Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection

    With Connection
        .Provider = "MSDASQL"
        .ConnectionString = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=" + Server + ";DATABASE=" + Database
        .ConnectionString = .ConnectionString + ";Trusted_Connection=Yes"
        .CommandTimeout = 60000
        .Open
    End With

End Sub

Public Function RunSQL(SQL As String) As ADODB.Recordset

  Set RunSQL = Connection.Execute(SQL)

End Function
```

Comment: Assuming this would only be run from within one of the modules... wouldn't be as simple as not creating any update/insert/delete statements? And from SQL Server you can actually restrict the permissions at user level (to use SELECT only...).

Comment: Couldn't you just check the query type in `RunSQL` function and block it at that stage? (i.e. if it is an UPDATE query, just don't execute it)

Comment: @DarXyde Indeed server side would be ideal, however the customer has asked for this instead. I don't plan either to use anything but select statements, but has been requested if it was possible to do this as an extra security.

Comment: Yes, a good workaround as well @Zac, if it's not possible to make the connection as a Read-Only that might have to be a workaround.

Comment: Agree with Zac, that might be a way... but what is going to stop whoever wants to execute that update, to go and change `RunSQL`? Or write their own function to connect and run sql? From a client perspective, if they want to be sure, then permissions in SQL Server should be the way...

Comment: By default, SQL Server does not assign any permissions to an account, except the permission to log in -- you can't even select any data unless you're allowed to. The simple way of making a connection "read only" is to ensure the account simply has no permissions granted to change anything. Note that by default, you also *have no permission to log in at all*, so "server-side" security is exactly what you want here -- someone already made the choice to give you permission to do something, one way or another. No DBA worth their salt would trust restrictions implemented only on the client end.